# Est-ce que Tintin est un vrai prénom?

Tags: noms-propres, prénoms

Est-ce que Tintin est un vrai prénom ? Est-ce un diminutif d'un prénom plus long ? Est-ce une invention de la part de Hergé ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dans une [interview](http://www.lexpress.fr/culture/livre/bd/tintin-s-explique_479047.html) de Tintin lui-même, celui-ci indique que son nom, comme celui de Milou, sont uniquement le fruit de sonorités, Hergé ayant du les inventer en vitesse:

> Oui, c'est cela. Tintin et Milou sont nés le même jour. Hergé m'a raconté qu'il nous avait créés en moins d'une journée parce que tout d'un coup le directeur du journal dans lequel il travaillait a voulu faire un supplément pour la jeunesse. Hergé en a été chargé et le malheureux a dû créer instantanément quelque chose. Je suis né ainsi : par hasard. Et pour mon nom, Tintin, pour celui de Milou aussi, c'est la même chose : le hasard des sonorités.

Il est donc clair que *Tintin* n'était pas un prénom à cette époque. De nos jours, comme Shlublu l'[indique](https://french.stackexchange.com/posts/1491), il est utilisé comme surnom ou diminutif, mais certainement en référence à la bande dessinée.

Answer (score 4):

Il n'y a pas de liste officielle de prénoms que l'on pourrait qualifier de vrais, mais *Tintin* n'est pas un prénom usuel, non, ni un diminutif.

Le seul Tintin dont j'ai jamais entendu parler est celui de la bande dessinée. Il arrive par contre que Tintin soit utilisé comme surnom, et c'est vraisemblablement en référence à la BD.

Comment: Je l'ai déjà entendu aussi comme diminutif de _Valentin_, mais je doute fort que ça aie précédé la bande dessinée.

Comment: Tintin comme diminutif spontané de Valentin ne m'étonnerait pas chez de jeunes enfants.

Comment: Entendu hier dans une pièce de théâtre comme diminutif de *Martin* pour une mère désignant son fils.

Comment: On peut supposer que c'est consécutif à la bande dessinée, non?

Answer (score 4):

Tintin est un personnage de la *Guerre des boutons* de Louis Pergaud, 1912.

> — D'abord, qu'est-ce c'est t'y que ça, des couilles molles ? » fit Tintin.

p. 19 de l'édition en Livre de Poche de 1963.